# Is there a simple way to invert an integer function that experiences overflow?

Tags: java, math, binary, integer-overflow

I'm trying to create an inverse function for the java.util.Random setSeed and next functions. Essentially I want to be able to input a long value (before it's truncated to 48 bits) and get back a seed or family of seeds that will result in that value for the first nextLong() call. Its relevant source code is below:

setSeed(long seed)

```
seed = (seed ^ 0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
```

next(int bits)

```
//this function is called by nextLong()
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1)
```

The problem seems to occur because of the second part, as the integer overflows after the multiplication. Because of this, I can't simply divide out the constant as it will end up with a different result and will NOT give me the correct seed.

I'm not very experienced in binary operations and was wondering if there's a way to account for this overflow when dividing to obtain the correct seed without having to guess what the really big post-multiplication number actually was.

Comment: Not only does it overflow, but the truncated result furthermore has its 16 most significant bits masked off.

Comment: It might be possible to compute a seed that produces a specific `long` as the first result, but that would depend on more complete details of `nextLong()`'s computation.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/how-can-i-determine-the-initial-values-of-pseudo-random-number-generator-if-the), it asks a very similar question.

Comment: `nextLong()` uses 32 bits from two consecutive calls to the underlying LCG, taking only the middle 32 bits from each state. It may not be "hard" to solve in a cryptographic sense, but I do not think it is trivial either.

Comment: Probably more of a math question, if you don't get an answer here, try math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if what you really want is a random number generator, where the first number generated is a specific value.

```
class MyRandom extends java.util.Random {
    long targetValue;
    long offset;
    int count=0;

    public MyRandom(long target) {
        this.targetValue = target;
   } 

   public long nextLong() {
        long rnd = super.nextLong();
        if(count++==0) {
            offset = target - rnd;
        }
        return rnd + offset;
   }
}
```

On the first call to nextLong it will set the offset and return target. 
On all calls it will return the random number shifted by a fixed amount. This should give a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks but no, I wanted a way to control the first output specifically for the RNG built into java.util.Random